# No customer group assigned

Tags: customer, customer-account, customer-group, magento2.3.5-p1

We have 3 customer groups: General, Jobber, Wholesale

For some reason, when a customer create an account on frontend, no customer group is assigned.
In the backend we cannot create a new customer from the sales page because the customer group drop down is missing. I have to go to customer section to create a new customer and assign a group.

I did try to setup the automatic group assignment to general group, but then rule apply to wholesale group as if they were general.

Any idea how to assign all new customers to General while still being able to manually assign Wholesale from backend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check below settings

Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options

You'll find Default Group where you can change the value. The group you select there (provided that the Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group option above is set to Yes) will be the default group assigned to every new customer

Comment: Hey Lokesh thanks for your answer, unfortunately this would work but for some reason when this option is selected, wholesale pricing using catalog price rule won't apply.